# My UI Canvas doesn't show up when I export .apk for Ouclus Quest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I have an app, it downloads an Asset Bundle (A video basically) which is played as a 360 video in VR on Oculus Quest. The flow is as follows:

[image: Canvas Settings]

1. Video Dashboard, user clicks on Download button to begin the download.
   [image: Video Dashboard]
2. Downloading UI element is activated (THIS IS WHAT I AM NOT ABLE TO SEE) even though, I am able to see the first part of the canvas.
   [image: Download Video Panel]
3. Once the video is downloaded, then I can play the video in 360.

For reference, I am attaching images in the same numeric order as flow. Also I noticed, I am missing an option on my Event System, right on this script: [image: Missing Option]

Note: When I hit play right inside Unity 3D with my oculus connected via oculus link, I can see the downloading panel but I never get to see when I make a build or build and run.

VR Hardware: Oculus Quest 2
Unity 3D Version: 2020.3.4f1

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you really want your world space canvas the dimensions 1920 * 1080 units?

Comment: @derHugo I was first coding it as a standalone app but then I shifted to VR dev. Not sure what are the right pixel units because I thought 1920*1080 is standard HD and Oculus has more pixels in general. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: What I try to hint you is that a **Screenspace** Canvas is in **pixel** dimensions but a **Worldspace** one is in Unity units dimensions! So currently you tell it to have 1.9 * 1.0 km size